# Alpha Filter and Gradient Filter

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, gradient, alpha

I have a issues with css filters for IE8 ... I have one div with gradient background and this div need to have opacity 0 .. when you hover with mouse over div he get opacity 1 ... my code look like this...

```
#myDiv {
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
opacity: 0;
background:rgba(75,29,79,0.85); /* For modern browsers */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=1, StartColorStr='#D84B1D4F', EndColorStr='#D84B1D4F')"; /* For IE8 */
}
```

and then I have hover for this div

```
#myDiv:hover {
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
opacity: 1;
}
```

but it does not work .. I guess because it uses both filters, Is there an option that they work together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the display property is set for both. For instance: try setting `display:block` for the aforementioned div.

Also you can reset the transparency with `-ms-filter: "";`

Try:

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#D84B1D4F",endColorstr="#D84B1D4F",GradientType=1);
```

Bear in mind that the first 2 digits of your rgb value are setting the opacity so there is no need to use opacity as well. You could use `visibility:hidden` for example.

Comment: ahh yes I can use visibility:hidden .. I use opacity because I want to hide #myDiv completely and all inner elements in this div.. this is reason I want to use opacity.. but I totally forget on visibility:hidden

Comment: Cool, happy it worked for you. Then you can accept my answer :)